# Show data of a month instead of 12 months

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, highcharts

I want to show the X axis of my highchart in months, eg, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" etc...

However as I am using an array, I don't know how I can show it.

My code:

```
Private _months() As String = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }
Dim array3 As New ArrayList
For Each row In _months
    array3.Add(_months)
Next row
```

Using this, the chart shows the whole month of the year for 1 data, so for data 1, it will show...

```
Array[12]
0: Array[12]
1: Array[12]
2: Array[12]
3: Array[12]
4: Array[12]
5: Array[12]
6: Array[12]
7: Array[12]
8: Array[12]
9: Array[12]
10: Array[12]
11: Array[12]
length: 12
__proto__: Array[0]
```

...but I want to show one array of one month, and not all 12..

Any ideas on how this can be done using my code?

Comment: you are adding the whole `_months` array into `array3` for each month in `_months`. Change your `array3.Add(_months)` to `array3.Add(row)`.

Comment: thanks lol, thats done it.

however, what if i want the first data to start with March depending on what the data is...

Comment: @mali - Then that would be a new question.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat - Despite what the FAQ says, that should really be an answer. If you post the answer yourself, I will delete the wiki answer. (Just leave a comment on the answer so that I get a notification.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment by [ajakblackgoat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2264365/ajakblackgoat)

> you are adding the whole `_months` array into `array3` for each month in `_months`. Change your `array3.Add(_months)` to `array3.Add(row)`.